# Need advice to delimit the tilde when using awk over ssh remote connection

Tags: linux, awk

Good day.

I'm trying to delimit the tilde while using awk over an ssh remote connection.  When I run the command on the localhost the command works as expected. When I try to use the same command on a remote server, it returns a syntax error.

```
-bash-4.2$ /opt/SMAW/bin/RtpDumpLog -s 2111250000 | awk '$4 ~ /major/ { print }'
05-12-2021 02:11:20  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[32721]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:11:21  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[32724]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:11:22  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[32726]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:11:25  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[911]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:11:27  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[914]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:12:10  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[1081]: fatal: Write failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:12:11  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[1083]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
05-12-2021 02:15:24  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[2332]: fatal: Write failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]"
06-12-2021 19:18:14  141-9994  major        "OEM:cscf0002vm003oam001:sshd: sshd[30695]: fatal: Write failed: Broken pipe [preauth]"
```

To remote server:

```
-bash-4.2$ ssh -q 192.168.210.142 "/opt/SMAW/bin/RtpDumpLog -s 2111250000 | awk '$4 ~ /major/ { print }'"
awk: cmd. line:1:  ~ /major/ { print }
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

I tried using a backslash to delimit the tilde:

```
-bash-4.2$ ssh -q 192.168.210.142 "/opt/SMAW/bin/RtpDumpLog -s 2111250000 | awk '$4 \~ /major/ { print }'"
awk: cmd. line:1:  \~ /major/ { print }
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Please advise.

Regards,
Bjoern

Comment: It's not about the tilde, it's about [double-quoted](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690) `$4`. You may find this useful: [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50853067/1745001

Answer (score 1):

Don't run `awk` on the remote host:

```bsh
ssh -q 192.168.210.142 /opt/SMAW/bin/RtpDumpLog -s 2111250000 |
awk '$4 == "major"'
```

The issue is not the tilde but the fact that you use `$4` in a double-quoted string.  You will notice that the `$4` was removed since its value was empty in the calling shell.

If you need to run the full pipeline on the remote host, I would suggest doing it using a script given as a quoted here-document:

```bsh
ssh -q 192.168.210.142 sh -s <<'SCRIPT_END'
/opt/SMAW/bin/RtpDumpLog -s 2111250000 |
awk '$4 == "major"'
SCRIPT_END
```

With `-s`, `sh` will read the commands from its standard input stream, which is connected to `ssh`, which gets it from the here-document.  I'm choosing to invoke `sh` explicitly here as I don't know what your login shell is.  If it is a standard `sh`-like shell, then you may possibly drop `sh -s`.